# ref a table correctly inside enumerate items

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]

\item  \textbf{ aaaaaaa}
\item \textbf{bbbbbbb}
\begin{sidewaystable} % <-- HERE
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}\hline
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text \\\hline
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text \\
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text \\
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text \\
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text \\
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some caption to the table.}
\label{table1}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{enumerate}

now I WANT REF A TABLE \ref{table1} but it returns the item's order.not because it is the first table.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Surely you need a case where it makes a difference to the output? Here, both counters are at 1 anyway.

Comment: the ref is referencing the table not the list item.

Comment: If you add a second item to before the table, you'll see that the reference is still to table 1 - it does not become 2 as it would if it was referencing the order within the enumeration.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific in terms of what you're after? A title-only, code-only question is very ambiguous in general. Add some mortar to your bricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a second item, you can see that the correct reference is being used as the reference is still to 1 (the table number) even though the order within the enumeration is now 2 (the item number):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
  \item  aaaaaaa
  \item\label{enum:something} something
  \begin{sidewaystable} % <-- HERE
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}\hline
      dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text \\\hline
      dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text \\
      dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text \\
      dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text \\
      dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text \\
      dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & dummy text \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Some caption to the table.}
    \label{table1}
  \end{sidewaystable}
\end{enumerate}

Now I want to reference the table \ref{table1} and it returns the table's number and not the number of the item in the enumeration (\ref{enum:something}).
\end{document}
```

[image: comparative referencing]